# Error when using setOrgWideEmailAddressId in SingleEmailMessage [resolved]

Tags: apex, email, error, singleemailmessage

I'm trying using setOrgWideEmailAddressId in my class Apex but he return this error: 718403274-125341 (195485361)

Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void sendEmailReference(String strEmail){
    OrgWideEmailAddress orgAddress = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM 
    OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE DisplayName = 'Atendimento'];
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgAddress.Id);
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {strEmail}; 
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    String htmlBody = 'hello';
    mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
```

What can it be?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html

Comment: Have you verified the Org WIde email address in setup? also is the running profile has access to that org wide address

Comment: Thank you guys, Pranay it's worked for me, someone deselected "Allow All Profiles to Use this From Address" in Organization-Wide Email Addresses, thank you very much

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Please post an answer so the OP can accept and properly close this question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one tries to send email using [OrgWideEmailAddress](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_orgwide_addresses_considerations.htm&type=5) and does not have profile access, one gets a gack.

Fix: Add that profile to OrgWideEmailAddress supported profile list.